# Dynamic Links Firebase only work the first time

Tags: swift, firebase, dynamic, hyperlink, firebase-dynamic-links

I am adding the Firebase Dynamic Links in my iOS App. I made the configuration according to the documentation and until this point, all right.
When testing, I noticed that the link opens the app and calls the method:

```
application (_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey: Any]
```

And works!

But when I click the link (dynamic link) again, it just opens the app and does not call the method.

Can someone help me?

My code:

```
private func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity,
                     restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
        let handled = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().handleUniversalLink(userActivity.webpageURL!) { (dynamiclink, error) in
//            let vc = NomeStoryboard.instance.configuracoes.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "idSB_ConfiguracoesApp_Onboard") as! ConfiguracoesAppPageViewController
//            UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = vc
        }

        return handled
    }

    @available(iOS 9.0, *)
    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {
        return application(app, open: url,
                           sourceApplication: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
                           annotation: "")
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
        if let dynamicLink = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().dynamicLink(fromCustomSchemeURL: url) {
            // Handle the deep link. For example, show the deep-linked content or
            // apply a promotional offer to the user's account.
            // ...
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` returns true.
2. Looks like you have a slightly older version of `continueUserActivity` -- maybe try the more modern signature:

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, 
      restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool
```